# Can Conditional Normalizing Flows Cheat?

Tags: bayesian-deep-learning

Consider the Conditional Normalizing Flow (informally): $f(x, z) = y$ with its inverse $f^{-1}(x, y) = z$ where $x$ is the prior and $z$ is the posterior.

Is $f^{-1}$ able to "cheat" by leaking information about $y$ directly into $z$, or do the theoretical guarantees of normalizing flows side-step this?

I want to use $z$ as a way to represent anything about $y$ that can't be deduced from only $x$ (similar to [BYOL-Hindsight](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=fIH2G4fnSy)) so that I can randomly sample from $z$ for inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, the functions of your conditional normalizing flow are $f(y, x) = z$ and $f^{-1}(z, x) = y$, where we model the likelihood of $y$ conditional on $x$.

The probability density can be expressed as:

$$
p_{Y \vert X}(y \vert x) = p_{Z \vert X}(z \vert x) \vert J \vert
$$

In optimizing the $p_{Y \vert X}$ term of the objective, the model learns $z$ to represent how "unpredictable" $y$ is, being incentivised to learn the highest probability that doesn't lose any information.

> Is $f^{−1}$ able to "cheat" by leaking information about $y$ directly into $z$, or do the theoretical guarantees of normalizing flows side-step this?

Now, when passed through the inverse, only the information about $y$ that it "couldn't have known" is preserved through $z$, which is what $f^{-1}$ receives.

Conditional normalizing flows might not be what you're looking for in adapting BYOL-Hindsight because the likelihood consists of both what it doesn't know and what it knows it can't know. Having the actor look for places with lower probability would likely reproduce the noisy tv problem.

Perhaps you could instead use it to task the agent to find states with high probability, that the model still doesn't predict well.